# filtering the value not in the range

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here I am trying to filter (remove) the rows pos_axillary nodes more than 30. The below code is not displaying me any values.

```
l=list(range(0,30))
l

pos_ax=[x for x in breast.Pos_axillary_nodes.unique() if a in x] 
pos_ax

breast = breast[df.Pos_axillary_nodes.isin(pos_ax)]
breast

Pos_axillary_nodes
1
3
0
2
4
10
0
0
9
30
1
10
7
0
13
0
1
0
0
0
0
6
15
0
21
2
0
0
3
1
0
11
1
5
0
0
0
0
2
4
2
0
0
23
0
0
0
8
0
0
8
0
0
1
0
0
1
2
4
20
0
1
52
2
0
0
14
2
3
0
2
0
4
6
9
19
0
1
0
16
6
0
1
0
0
14
0
0
1
2
3
5
20
0
3
0
23
0
0
0
6
0
0
3
4
4
12
11
11
7
8
2
0
0
0
10
1
0
0
1
1
3
0
1
13
0
0
6
0
1
1
2
0
0
4
1
13
3
7
1
0
1
3
2
3
4
0
4
0
4
5
0
1
0
0
0
4
1
3
9
24
12
1
1
2
1
0
11
23
5
7
7
3
0
46
0
7
19
1
0
6
15
1
0
1
18
0
3
22
1
9
3
0
2
1
0
0
5
14
1
9
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
3
1
0
0
3
2
35
0
0
1
4
0
7
3
17
0
1
2
25
0
5
0
1
0
0
0
8
0
0
13
0
19
6
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
9
28
0
22
0
0
0
0
2
22
15
0
0
0
2
0
1
0
13
0
1
0
8
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
8
0
0
0
0
4
14
0
0
8
0
2
0
0
0
3
0
0
3
0
1
0
3
1
2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have much details from your question. But what is "a" in the following code fragment?

```
pos_ax=[x for x in breast.Pos_axillary_nodes.unique() if a in x]
```

Also, I don't understand why you alternate between `breast` and `df` in `breast[df.Pos_axillary_nodes.isin(pos_ax)]`.

At least, I would expect to have `if x in l` instead of `if a in x`. Moreover, if `l` is simply a list of integers between 0 and 29, I suggest to write `if 0 <= x < 30` instead.

Finally, if the goal is to extract from 
`Pos_axillary_nodes` rows for which this value is comprised between 0 and 29, then the following will be much simpler:

```
breast[lambda d: d['Pos_axillary_nodes'].between(0, 29)]
```

Comment: can you tell me how at add one more condition for the above

Comment: You can combine conditions by using ``&`` between these conditions. For example, ``breast[lambda d: (d['Pos_axillary_nodes'] >= 0) & (d['Pos_axillary_nodes'] < 30)]``. Don't forget parentheses, as ``&`` has a different priority than ``and`` (which is **not** supported in this context!!).

Comment: breast[lambda d: (d['Pos_axillary_nodes'] <= 10) & (d['Years_of_operation'] < 65)]  in place of 65 i want to pass a list of values actually eg:filter_list = [58,62,64,65] ,breast[lambda d: (d['Pos_axillary_nodes'] <= 10) & (d['Years_of_operation'] < filter_list)],its displaying  broadcasting error

Comment: What does that mean "lower than a list"? What do you expect to have? Please open a new question, it will be easier.